# DetailView redirect not working in django

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, detailview

I keep getting a reverse error when i try to redirect from a DetailView and CreateView. ***I keep getting object has no attribute pk***. I have equally tried using : **args=[str(self.id)])** but i still get the error.

```
class check (DetailView)
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if...:
             return reverse('no_edit', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is the `DetailView` object, which indeed has no primary key. If you want to access the object, you normally can use `self.object`, but since you have overwritten the `get` method itself, that will not work either.

You can fix it by calling `self.get_object()` here, like:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class CheckView(DetailView):

    # …

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if …:
            return redirect('no_edit', pk=self.object.pk)
```

We can here make use of [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). This will construct a `HttpResponseRedirect` with the result of a `reverse` call.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning a redirect, just an URL, try doing something like

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(...))`